# omniauth with linkedin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to set up an authentication using using omniauth via linkedin. I am trying to follow the railscast #241 (Simple OmniAuth). Unfortunately I keep getting an error when I start my rails server in my local environment:

/Users/steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/omniauth-1.0.2/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:33:in `rescue in provider': Could not find matching strategy for :linked_in. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-linked_in). (LoadError)

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'sqlite3
```

Congfig/Initializer/Omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linked_in, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
end
```

I'm just a newbie so if not sure if other info is needed to clarify issue.
Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message has it for you: "You may need to install an additional gem (such as **omniauth-linked_in**)" Check out [omniauth-linked_in](http://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-linkedin) and see if that solves it for you.

Comment: Scott, thanks, so simple but I guess I just needed a kick in the right direction, once I added this gem, and then the multi_json gem, I was in good shape.

Answer (score 1):

the omniauth.rb file should be like the following. ( not like **linked_in**)

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedIn, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
end
```

Please read [omniauth-linkedin](https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin)! before you start to working on these.